# Вызов FacesContext из другого проекта

Tags: java, java-ee, jsf

Есть два проекта "A" и "B". Как я могу вызвать FacesContext, который используется в проекте "B" из "A" и например очистить его sessionMap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простой ответ: с помощью `FacesContext` - никак. `FacesContext` существует для конкретного "окна" конкретного приложения. Сервер связывает `FacesContext` с обращениями из браузера, не существует возможности "вклиниться" в эту связку извне (по крайней мере, простой возможности). Более того, даже в пределах одного приложения `FacesContext` существует не на всех стадиях обработки запроса из браузера, а появляется после того, как цепочка дошла до `FacesServlet.service`. Если посмотреть стек-трейсы обработки запросов, то зачастую можно увидеть десятки обработчиков (например, фильтров, отвечающих за безопасность), до того, как процесс доходит до `FacesServlet`.

Итого: `FacesContext` существует только в определённые моменты, и эти моменты возникают только в момент обращения из браузера, соответственно не получится просто в произвольный момент обратиться к `FacesContext`.

Тем не менее, взаимодействие приложений можно сделать другими способами. Обсуждение этих способов выходит за рамки заданного вопроса, Вы можете задать отдельный вопрос. Рекомендую перед этим провести самостоятельное исследование, что поможет хорошо сформулировать вопрос и, соответственно, получить на него качественный ответ (общие вопросы не приветствуются на Stackoverflow).

**PS** *Данные sessionMap хранятся в сессии, а сессия является объектом, существующем на сервере постоянно, в отличие от `FacesContext`. Вы можете повернуть свои исследования в эту сторону. Другой вариант - создать некоего менеджера сообщений, который принимает запросы на очистку из приложения A приложению B (с применением стандартных интеграционных протоколов, например REST/SOAP). В коде приложения B сделать некую проверку наличия запроса при получении обращений с клиента. Это просто абстракции, более конкретно решайте сами или просите помощи сообщества.*